# Why is %PYTHONPATH% being ignored by Python using cmd on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I developed a Python package on Linux, which works and my pytest succeeds.
I am making it Windows compatible.
I have say 'my_package' that sits in say 'C:\import_path\my_package'
I set the PYTHONPATH at the command line in my virtual environment like so:

```
set PYTHONPATH="C:\import_path"
echo %PYTHONPATH%
"C:\import_path"

# Python script identifies this
print('PYTHONPATH = {}'.format(os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH')))
"C:\import_path"
```

However any Python code referencing *my_package* when run from a Command Prompt where this *PYTHONPATH* has been explicitly set, will error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package'
```

However the code will run fine with *PYTHONPATH = C:\import_path* being set in the System Environment variables.
It also runs fine in VSCode with:

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "C:\\import_path"
    ]
```

Why is *python.exe* not reading the *%PYTHONPATH%* variable that was set in the cmd, but *python.exe* will read it when running in debug from VSCode or from the os system env variable?

Answer (score 1):

In all probability you are running from different shell session or calling different shell sessions and the variable is not parsed to all sessions. You could try setting it like this:

```
setx PYTHONPATH "C:\import_path" /M
```

When you set a variable you should set it system-wide if you intend to use multiple sessions.